# Cost of enumerating ILookup results? Better to always use Dictionary<TKey,List<TElement>>?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a `ILookup<TKey,TElement> lookup` from which I fairly often get elements and iterate trough them using LINQ or `foreach`. I look up like this `IEnumerable<TElement> results = lookup[key];`.

Thus, `results` needs to be enumerated at least once every time I use lookup results (and even more if I'm iterating multiple times if I don't use .ToList() first).

Even though its not as "clean", wouldn't it be better (performance-wise) to use a `Dictionary<TKey,List<TElement>>`, so that all results from a key are only enumerated on construction of the dictionary? Just how taxing is ToList()?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`ToLookup`, like all the other `ToXXX` LINQ methods, uses immediate execution. The resulting object has no reference to the original source. It effectively *does* build a `Dictionary<TKey, List<TElement>>` - not those exact types, perhaps, but equivalent to it.

Note that there's a difference though, which may or may not be useful to you - the indexer for a lookup returns an empty sequence if you give it a key which doesn't exist, rather than throwing an exception. That can make life much easier if you want to be able to just index it by any key and iterate over the corresponding values.

Also note that although it's not explicitly documented, the implementation used for the value sequences *does* implement `ICollection<T>`, so calling the LINQ `Count()` method is O(1) - it doesn't need to iterate over all the elements.

See my [Edulinq post on `ToLookup`](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/12/31/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-18-tolookup/) for more details.

Comment: ReSharper warns me about 'possible multiple enumeration of IEnumerable' when I use `results`. If I understand you correctly, I can safely ignore the warning for a `ILookup` created from `ToLookup`? (just the way I can ignore the same warning about Count() because it's O(1)?)

Comment: @David: Yes, that's right. It's cheap to iterate over a lookup subsequence. Sometimes ReSharper can be too smart for its own good ;)

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the implementation is `System.Linq.Lookup` (does `ILookup` have any other implementations?), the elements presented in `lookup[key]` are stored in an array of elements as a field of `System.Linq.Lookup.Grouping`. Repeatedly looking them up won't cause a re-iteration of source. Of course, rebuilding the `Lookup` will be more costly, but once built, the source is no longer accessed.